# How to deallocate memory on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

This is probably a very silly and simple question to most of you, but I have the following code creating a temporary array within a function, at the end of the function i need to release the memory. Here is the code:

```
double *FFTOut;

//FFT Out removes the alternative zeros added in the earler phase (before the FFT)
FFTOut = (double *)malloc((CFArray1Size)* sizeof(double));
```

So the pointer FFTOut is to a block of memory, I have tried the following...

```
[FFTOut release];
```

and...

```
[FFTOut dealloc];
```

Neither of which work. I'm sorry to post such a trivial question, but i can't seem to find the answer to this? Unless I am allocating the memory incorrectly in the first place, but I don't think this is the case?

Many Thanks

Comment: A rule to remember: if you see `dealloc` next to anything that is not `super` you made a mistake. No exceptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you malloc, you have to use free().

release is for objective-c object that you've either new'd or alloc'd.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response! Silly question really I know!!